# how to run WSA(Windows Subsystem for Android) as VM (Virtual Machine) in aws cloud service

Tags: android, windows, amazon-web-services, automated-tests, virtual-machine

I'm working on Automating an app for that I'm using WSA which is helpful to run android apps in windows 11 desktop. I'm having an setup for this in my windows 11 desktop.
but, I need to run setup in cloud for testing various apps, I have no idea about how to setup this in cloud (preferably AWS).
What are the ways to setup Windows subsystem for android in Cloud..
Any help would be appreciated...